# How to make a copy of a branch

Tags: git, github

I need to make a copy of my branch to another branch with a different name.
This new branch that was copied must have the same commits as the original branch.
In short, everything in it must be the same.
With the exception of the Branch name, which must be different.

Example:

**Branch (A)**
commit 1
commit 2

**Branch (Copy of A)**
commit 1
commit 2

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository

Comment: 1- Be in Branch A. 2- git checkout -b Branch B. 3- Branch B will be created and will be exaclty like Branch A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is trivial, thanks to the design of the data structures used by Git. Since a branch is (in essence) a label for a single commit and each commit knows its parent(s), we only need to create another label and have it point to the same commit. Nothing needs to be copied actually.

If you want to only create the branch:

```
git branch copy_of_a a
```

If you want to create and switch to the branch:

```
git checkout -b copy_of_a a
```

or with recent versions of Git:

```
git switch -c copy_of_a a
```

---

There's also the [`-c` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch/#Documentation/git-branch.txt--c) to

> Copy a branch, together with its config and reflog.

The other forms mentioned above will neither copy config nor reflog.

```
git branch -c a copy_of_a
```

(props to [@Guildenstern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725151/guildenstern))

Comment: You might as well use `git branch --copy` in order to get the config and reflog as well.

Comment: @Guildenstern oh cool, I wasn't aware of this option. Let me check it out

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to create new branch in same repository?
If your answer is 'yes', you can use `"git checkout -b newBranch"`

And then run `"git pull origin newBranch"`

I think it can resolve your problem.

OR run `"git push origin oldBranch: newBranch"...`

Answer (score 4):

if you have the branch in your local machine you can do it like this

1. checkout to the branch A `git checkout branchA`
2. Then you can create a new branch with `git checkout -b branchB`. this will create a new branch with all the commits in the `branchA`

if you want to do this in GitHub, follow these steps,

1. Navigate to you Repository
2. click on Branches
3. Click on "new branch" and give it your desired name. then select the source branch `branchA`
4. the press "Create new branch"

this will create a new branch with all the commits in the source branch.

in both the above cases, the new branch will be identical except the name

Answer (score 3):

Only one line code is necessary.
`"git push origin oldBranch: newBranch"`